# JavaFX - StackPane component jumping

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, java-8

i recently explored JavaFX and came across a simple login form executing the login via php script.
Based on the result the login form indicates an error label or redirects to a new scene.

During the actual login progress i want to show an progress bar which i exchange (visibility toggle) with an error label whenever the login did not succeed.

For some reason the progress bar jumps to a new position after the label appeared once.

**Video showing the bug behavior:**

[Video of the issue](http://www.youtube.com/embed/gUDjpzWgtBI)

**Minimal example to reproduce this behavior (JDK8, Language level=8):**

[Code sample](http://privatepaste.com/226291bf94)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the component is jumping because when your are applying `text` to the `Label`, the width of the `StackPane` is getting increased and the `ProgressBar` gets shifted to the `CENTER`.

For future references, you can check similar phenomenon by applying a style to the StackPane or any other Layout

```
<StackPane style=" -fx-border-color:black; 
                -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;">
```

To avoid this, you will have to wrap the `ProgressBar` in a `HBox` and set the `alignment of the HBox`

```
...
<Label id="login-status-label" fx:id="loginStatusLabel"  />
<HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
    <ProgressIndicator id="login-status-progress-indicator" 
          fx:id="loginStatusProgressIndicator" prefHeight="15.0" 
                                   prefWidth="15.0" visible="false"/>
</HBox>
...
```